# How to send ctrl+a+c to detached screen to create nested window?

Tags: gnu-screen

I tried following but it doesn't work...

```bsh
screen -S foo -d -m
screen -S foo -p 0 -X stuff "^Ac"
```

Trying to create two relate screen session windows that can be toggled using `ctrl+a+n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can `stuff` commands to screen itself, but you could just use `-X` to give the command to create a new window. That would be [the command `screen`](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Screen-Command).

```
screen -S foo -d -m
screen -S foo -X screen -t "another window"
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks so much for helping out... spent way to much time trying to figure this out!

Comment: Pushing my luck... perhaps you can help with https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646090/how-to-create-split-screen-and-run-commands-from-bash-script?