# How to create split screen and run commands from Bash script?

Tags: gnu-screen

The following doesn’t work given second command doesn’t run until first exits and when I try running first in background using `&`, I get following error.

I also tried running first in background using `-d -m`, but split doesn’t work.

> Must be connected to a terminal.

```bsh
screen -S test -t foo long_lived_process_1
screen -S test -X split
screen -S test -X focus down
screen -S test -X screen -t bar long_lived_process_2
```

Comment: `tmux` could probably solve it: https://lukaszwrobel.pl/blog/tmux-tutorial-split-terminal-windows-easily/ - section "scripting tmux"

Comment: Thanks @Jan... looking into tmux.

Comment: +1 for tmux. a good summary of tmux-vs-screen: https://mutelight.org/practical-tmux (contains also lots of exemples of config). screen is a wonderful tool (and quite ancient) but tmux is more recent and offers some benefits (maybe less portable though, and could introduce differences, some which are listed in the link I provided)

Comment: Problem solved using `tmux`. Still curious to know if this is possible using `screen`.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/688630/9689

Answer (score 1):

With `screen -S test some command`, it opens the screen right there, instead of sending it to the background. So, the script running those commands stops, the next commands don't get executed against that screen.

So, I guess we have to send it to the background initially, and then send the other commands.

```
screen -S test -d -m top 
screen -S test -X title foo
screen -S test -X split
screen -S test -X focus down
screen -S test -X screen -t bar watch free
screen -S test -R
```

I didn't get `-S test -d -m -t foo top` to work, the title didn't catch,
but the first window is a bit of a special case anyway. (Unless you just decide to keep it as a dummy and run `-X select 0`, `-X kill` at the end.)

You could also look at putting the commands in `screenrc`, there's examples in the man page about doing setup like this through that.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping out again. I naively used `ls` as an example... both commands are long lived so screen would not terminate (updated question).

Comment: "exists" or "exits"?

Comment: @sunknudsen, right, I got it wrong, starting the first window brings the whole screen to the foreground. Edited.